# Unreal Engine Can't Rotate Material

Tags: textures, maps, unreal, materials

I am a Blender artist and Unity Developer. I'm very familiar with materials and texture maps in Blender and I'm only moderately familiar with texture maps in Unity. My workflow is to do all of my modeling and texturing work in Blender, bake the diffuse, roughness, metallic, normal, and/or height maps and then import them into my game engine (usually Unity).

I'm trying something new and using Unreal Engine. I bought a materials pack that was made with Adobe Substance. I applied the texture and was able to make the textures smaller so it was applied as a repeating pattern.

So there are 2 things I am having trouble doing. I need to flip the texture so it is applied horizontally, and I need to make the pattern look less repetitive. It looks like the first thing is going to be easier than the second thing. Does Anyone know how to do this? Can I do it without downloading the substance addon?

This is what the texture looks like (un-flipped and repetitive):
[image]

And this is what the material looks like in the open editor; the L01 Tiling control was how I got the pattern to shrink and repeat:
[image]